# How to use initialisers or a constructor in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, mobile, initialization

I've been having problems with what should be a basic fundamental in Swift. When I'm coding, I often spend too much time with using variables and constants in classes. I think the reason I struggle is because I'm rooted in Java where everything is pretty much created in a constructor, so the `Class myVar = new Class()` is really familiar to me, but in Swift, I see both:

```
let userClient = UserClient()
let userService: UserService
...
init(userService: UserService) {
  self.userService = userService
}
```

The way I see it, it's kind of like passing something across multiple classes?

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.

I understand this. Great. But why don't we always just declare things like `let iNeedThisFunctionality = Functionality()`.

Sorry if this idea is really basic, it annoys me that I can create complex UIs and user authentication and all that, but I consistently trip up on this. I kinda just rely on xcode to tell me I've declared something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm rooted in Java where everything is pretty much created in a constructor

You *can* do everything in the initialiser if you want:

```
class Foo {
    let userClient: UserClient
    let userService: UserService

    init(userService: UserService) {
        self.userService = userService
        self.userClient = UserClient()
    }
}
```

It's just that the initialisation of `userClient` doesn't depend on any initialiser parameter, or `self`, so it can be done inline:

```
let userClient = UserClient()
```

> But why don't we always just declare things like `let iNeedThisFunctionality = Functionality()`?

You can't initialise `userService` this way because it needs to be initialised to the initialiser parameter. i.e. when you create a `Foo`:

```
let foo = Foo(userService: someService)
```

`foo.userService` needs to be `someService`. The design of `Foo` requires that to create a `Foo`, you need to pass a `UserService` to it, and its `userService` property will be initialised to that service.

If you are "rooted in Java", you should have seen this kind of code in Java too:

```java
public class Foo {
    private final UserClient userClient = new UserClient();
    private final UserService userService;

    public Foo(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

That's how I would translate your Swift code to Java. You can do "both" too.

Comment: Thank you so so much Sweeper! I feel like I can see through the fog now, this has really helped. Thank you for your time and effort in this post!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with wether it's a stored property or a computed property. See this documentation for more info: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html